# Can someone help me to fix this function?

Tags: flutter

I got errors when create this function... The errors on line 50 and 53 at `b1.getLineTo1(p1)` and `b2.getLineTo2(p2)`... It's Flutter and I want to make the line between two or more objects.

Thanks for advance

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

enum Place { left, top, right, bottom }

class Bound {
  double x;
  double y;
  Place place;

  Bound({this.x, this.y, this.place});

  List<Line> getLineTo1(Bound to) {
    return [Line(b1: Bound(), p1: Point())];
  }

  List<Line> getLineTo2(Bound to) {
    return [Line(b2: Bound(), p2: Point())];
  }
}

class Point {
  double x;
  double y;

  Point({this.x, this.y});

  List<Line> checkPoint(Point space) {
    return [Line(p1: Point(), p2: Point())];
  }
}

class Line {
  Bound b1;
  Bound b2;
  Point p1;
  Point p2;

  Line({this.b1, this.b2, this.p1, this.p2});
}

void main1() {
  test("Left to Top", () {
    Bound b1 = Bound(place: Place.left, x: 0, y: 0);
    Bound b2 = Bound(place: Place.top, x: -20, y: 20);
    Point p1 = Point(x: b2.x + 5, y: b1.y);
    Point p2 = Point(x: b2.x, y: b1.y + 5);
    double radius;
    radius = 2 * 22 / 7 * 5 / 4;

    List<Line> lines1 = b1.getLineTo1(p1);
    expect(lines1?.length, 2);

    List<Line> lines2 = b2.getLineTo2(p2);
    expect(lines2?.length, 2);

    List<Line> linesRadius = p1.checkPoint(p2);
    expect(linesRadius?.length, radius);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the following functions:

```
  List<Line> getLineTo1(Bound to) {
    return [Line(b1: Bound(), p1: Point())];
  }

  List<Line> getLineTo2(Bound to) {
    return [Line(b2: Bound(), p2: Point())];
  }
```

Take a parameter of type `Bound`, but here in your code:

```
    Point p1 = Point(x: b2.x + 5, y: b1.y);
    Point p2 = Point(x: b2.x, y: b1.y + 5);
    double radius;
    radius = 2 * 22 / 7 * 5 / 4;

    List<Line> lines1 = b1.getLineTo1(p1);
    expect(lines1?.length, 2);
```

You are giving it an argument of type `Point` and not `Bound`, therefore change the argument or the parameter according to your requirement.